# FFmpeg Generate Thumbnail Efficiently

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg for generating timeline thumbnail preview (image preview when your hover over seekbar in video player , like youtube player)

I need generating thumbnail for every 20s .
Here is code i use :

`ffmpeg -i vide.mp4 -vf "fps=4/60 ,scale=260:150,tile=10*10" -qscale:v 10  thumbnail_%d.jpg`

Code Work's Fine , only problem i have it's slow , for a movie with 3 hour long it's take more than 6 minute to generate thumbnail.

My System spec : Max os x 10.12 , Core i5 6600 , 16GB Ram.

I want's know there's a better way to do this ?

Comment: I would say to make thumbnails based on the length, so for the 3-hour long movie you only have 10 thumbnails maybe and not 300+.
Also, try to execute this command async so that you don't make the user wait for the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for this:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video

And more spefically **-vframes** parameter.

Comment: hi , can you give me an example ? i already use -vf parameter.

Comment: Actually I'm on Ubuntu so I'm using avconv instead of ffmpeg, however in my case when I run:
avconv -i video.mp4 -vf "scale=260:150" -qscale:v 10 -vframes 10 thumbnail%d.jpg
it will generate 10 thumbnails, but when I do that without -vframes parameter it generates 3000 thumbnails (depending on video length) and takes obviously a lot longer. Btw I think -vf and -vframes are not the same parameter.